# redis hset and key space notification

Tags: redis

I am using Redis 2.8 key space Pub/Sub notification, I would like to know if it is possible to get notified of *which* field changed after `HSET` command?

At the moment I receive the notification for the key as a consequence of the
`HSET` command, but I would better know which field has been set - I understand I can read again the set to look at differences once I am notified, but I don't find it very efficient.

Comment: If you're using StackExchange.Redis, I started work on an IDatabase implementation that raises custom notifications, including name of touched hash field. You can do the same thing for whatever Redis library you're using. https://github.com/johnnycardy/StackRedis.L1/tree/master/StackRedis.L1.Notifications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard Redis keyspace notifications do not include data about the data that was changes, and specifically do not include information about the touched Hash field.

Comment: I realized that. So there is no hope? What could I do to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: There's always hope - please do not despair :) Instead of using only notifications you could, for example, have another field in the Hash that stores the most-recently changed field's name. Of course, your app will need to keep it updated and there's always a chance that your notification subscriber may miss an update (or more) but that's also true for simple pubsub so I guess you can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't really what you want, it can still be used as a workaround.
Try to have unique hash key name, for example:

```
redis.hmset('task:{}'.format(unique_id), status='running')
```

And when you receive a message, it will look like this:

```
(b'__keyspace@0__:task:c81b8373-b5ea-4be0-b8f1-b490e7280898', 'hset')
```

Now, knowing unique task id, you can do:

```
redis.hget('task:{}'.format(unique_id), 'status')
> running
```